# Pandas string contains and replace

Tags: python, string, pandas, text, contains

I have the following dataframe

```
         A            B
0        France        United States of America
1        Italie        France
2        United Stats  Italy
```

I'm looking for a function that can take (for each word in column `A`) the first 4 letters and then search in column `B` whether or not these 4 letters are there. Now if this is the case, I want to replace the value in A with the similar value (similar first 4 letters) in `B`.

Example : for the word Italie in column `A`, I have to take `Ital` then search in `B` whether or not we can find it. Then I want to replace `Italie` with its similar word `Italy`.

I've tried to do `for` with `str.contains` function

But still cannot take only the first 4 letters.

Output expected :

```
         A                         B
0        France                   United States of America
1        Italy                    France
2        United Stats of America  Italy
```

In order to summarize, I am looking for correcting values in column A to become similar to those in column b

Comment: This need fuzzy match first then using map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution from fuzzy match --`fuzzywuzzy`

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

def fuzzyreturn(x):
    return [process.extract(x, df.B.values, limit=1)][0][0][0]


df.A.apply(fuzzyreturn)
Out[608]: 
0                      France
1                       Italy
2    United States of America
Name: A, dtype: object
df.A=df.A.apply(fuzzyreturn)
```

Comment: Wow, your fuzzyreturn function works wonderfully, I have to say I did not fully understand how it works, I quickly searched for fuzzywuzzy.process.extract
But I did not understand the significance of [0][0][0]

Comment: @Math just pull out the result without 0you will see why I need that many 0and []